# Apple watch, register complication to backend server on add

Tags: ios, watchkit

So we are trying to determine if we can use apple watch default inside of getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication to run a NSURLSession to register the device for notification updates on our backend. I can't find anything on anyone having done this. Will this count against the complication budget? Will it even run or do we need to do this through the watch app or iphone app with some data set?

- (void)getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTemplate *complicationTemplate))handler {
  }

Comment: As a side note through testing you can make a call, however, this is called during installation and not during runtime.

Comment: So If anyone starts having this same question here is the information I have figured out. You don't want to do it during - (void)getTimelineStartDateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complicaton withHandler:(void(^)(NSDate *date))handler {} because this counts against your cpu time max you can have. Instead we decided to move it into the app registration if it was an os2 watch. We will then push notifications and if they have an active complication we will do something with notification otherwise ignore the push notification.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'd want to use the new `PKPushTypeComplication` that was added in iOS 9. The [WWDC talk on WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713) has a big section towards the end on different strategies for updating your complication, and goes through the push updates from server case in quite a bit of detail.

The general approach seems to be that your iOS app will register its desired push types with PKPushRegistry, and upload the push tokens to your server. Then your server can send the pushes to the device, but they will only be delivered to the phone app if the complication is currently active on the watch. When receiving a push of type `PKPushTypeComplication` the iOS app should use WCSession's `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:` to send an immediate userInfo to the watch extension which will be woken up and given a chance to receive the userInfo and update the complication with the new data.